# Have GROUP BY return NULL if any values are null?

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about how to write a SQL query to coalesce rows such that if *any* rows in the GROUP BY are null, the value output is null. If MIN() treated nulls like zero then I would be all set, but it doesn't. I know why it doesn't, and I'm fine with it, but I'm not sure how to work around this.

This is probably clearer with an example. Let's say I have the following table. Call it `jobs`:

```
PK    FK Start                End
===== == ==================== ====================
1     7  2018-08-14 14:43:27  2018-08-14 14:43:31
2     7  2018-08-14 14:43:28  2018-08-14 14:43:35
3     8  2018-08-14 14:44:19  NULL
4     8  2018-08-14 14:44:19  2018-08-14 14:44:27
5     9  2018-08-14 14:45:03  NULL
6     10 2018-08-14 14:45:08  2018-08-14 14:45:11
```

There's a foreign-key relationship to another table, call it `requests`, where one request can point to one or more jobs, linked via the `FK` column.

So the sample data I've provided shows:

- Request #7 spawned two jobs that both completed
- Request #8 spawned two jobs, *one* of which has completed
- Request #9 spawned one job which has not completed
- Request #10 spawned one job which has completed.

I want to produce a query that outputs `FK`, `Start`, and `END`, where it's grouping by `FK` and using `MIN(Start)` and `MAX(End)` *unless* any values of `End` for that grouping are null, in which case I want to output null.

So for my example data, this is the desired output:

```
FK Start                End
== ==================== ====================
7  2018-08-14 14:43:27  2018-08-14 14:43:35
8  2018-08-14 14:44:19  NULL
9  2018-08-14 14:45:03  NULL
10 2018-08-14-14:45:08  2018-08-14 14:45:11
```

I can use that data to quickly see that any row with a null `End` value still has one or more job in progress. If `End` is not null I know all jobs for that request completed, and subtracting `Start` from it tells me the total time elapsed from the start of this request's first job to the end of its last job.

I hoped I could use `SELECT FK, MIN(Start), MAX(End) FROM jobs GROUP BY FK` but forgot that the defined behavior is to skip over the null value (the *"Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation"* message I get in the console).

So does anyone have any guidance on how I can *not* skip the null value and in fact force it to override any non-null values in that grouping? I thought of using CASE statements but I basically need to say "if this job's `End` is not null but another one's is, return null for this job" and I can't think of how to phrase this in SQL.

Thanks for any help,

-joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ISNULL`. You can use a nested query to replace the values that you set the `ISNULL` with null like so:

```
SELECT 
    FK, 
    case when Start = '1900-01-01' then null else Start end as Start, 
    case when End = '9999-12-31' then null else End end as End
FROM (
    SELECT
       FK, 
       MIN(ISNULL(Start, '1900-01-01')) as Start, 
       MAX(ISNULL(End, '9999-12-31')) as End 
       FROM jobs GROUP BY FK
) t
```

Comment: Thank you! I was starting to think subqueries might be necessary when I saw your answer. I tweaked your SQL (the example I posted is of course simplified) and it works just like I wanted. I am always concerned about subquery performance but the execution plan looks good and it ran quickly against a realistic dataset.

Comment: Since I know `Start` will never be null, here's the effective final SQL. My field is actually called `EndTimestamp` but for brevity I used `End` which is a reserved word, so I've bracketed it below. You can't use newlines in SO comments so apologies for the mess. Just replace `\n` with a newline to rehydrate it: `SELECT\nFK, \nStart, \nCASE\nWHEN [End] = '9999-12-31' THEN NULL\nELSE [End]\nEND AS [End]\nFROM (\nSELECT\nFK,\nMIN(Start) Start,\nMAX(ISNULL([End], '9999-12-31')) AS [End]\nFROM\njobs WITH(NOLOCK)\nGROUP BY FK\n) t`